# Objective C get item from object

Tags: objective-c, nslog

I have this code:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [self.tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);
```

and in my logs it returns this:

```
2015-09-01 15:21:58.581 App[1253:560973] {
    Name = "PDF-Folder";
    Type = Directory;
}
```

my question is how do I just get the `Name` ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
NSLog(@"%@", [[self.tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Name"]);
```